# Included dependencies in Spring

Tags: spring

I'm refactoring a big project which includes a lot of dependencies ; I have found that some of them comes with spring or spring boot.

Is there a simple way to check if a dependency already comes with Spring ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you use Maven, you can view the dependency tree using the command

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

Comment: More information here : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html